# Principal Ideal of a regular ring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, idempotents

Prove that if every principal left ideal of a ring R is generated by an idempotent, the ring R is [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_ring).

Comment: it is very easy to prove the converse that if a ring is regular then every principal left ideal is generated by an idempotent but i am struggling with this part

Comment: Younought to include the struggles you had.

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary $x$, if $Rx=Re$ for an idempotent $e$, you get $rx=e$ and $x=se$.

Two trivial computations later, you verify that one of the elements written here already shows $x$ is regular. The set of candidates here is so small you should have no trouble finding it.